# Read 4 lines of data into one row of pandas data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have txt file with such values:

```
108,612,620,900
168,960,680,1248
312,264,768,564
516,1332,888,1596
```

I need to read all of this into a single row of data frame.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7    8   9   10  11  12  13   14  15
0 108 612 620 900 168 960 680 1248 312 264 768 564 516 1332 888 1596
```

I have many such files and so I'll keep appending rows to this data frame.

I believe we need some kind of regex but I'm not able to figure it out. For now this is what I have :

```
df = pd.read_csv(f,sep=",| ", header = None)
```

But this takes `,` and (space) as separators where as I want it to take newline as a separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test/t.txt', header=None)
```

It gives you a DataFrame shaped like the CSV.  Then concatenate:

```
s = pd.concat((df.loc[i] for i in df.index), ignore_index=True)
```

It gives you a Series:

```
0      108
1      612
2      620
3      900
4      168
5      960
6      680
7     1248
8      312
9      264
10     768
11     564
12     516
13    1332
14     888
15    1596
dtype: int64
```

Finally, if you really want a horizontal DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame([s])
```

Gives you:

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7    8    9    10   11   12    13   14    15
0  108  612  620  900  168  960  680  1248  312  264  768  564  516  1332  888  1596
```

Since you've mentioned in a comment that you have many such files, you should simply store all the Series in a list, and construct a DataFrame with all of them at once when you're finished loading them all.